# dhcp server not assigning ip (centos 7)

Tags: linux, centos, centos7, dhcp-server

I configured a DHCP server on centOS 7 (`192.168.1.103`) but it's not assigning an IP address to the client (using Windows as client).

I am not getting any errors while starting/restarting the service.

Here is my DHCP configuration file (`/etc/dhcp/dhcpd.conf`)

```
subnet 192.168.1.0 netmask 255.255.255.0 {
  range 192.168.1.110 192.168.1.250;
  option subnet-mask 255.255.255.0;
  option routers 192.168.1.103;
  option broadcast-address 192.168.1.255;
  option domain-name-servers 8.8.8.8;
}

/etc/sysconfig/dhcp

DHCPDARGS=enp0s6u1
```

how this can be solved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add these options before the subnet line.

```
default-lease-time 600;
max-lease-time 7200;
authoritative;
```

also add a

```
;
```

To your dhcpargs, make sure that is exactly your interface with the IP in the same network.